# unable to create folder on ubuntu destkop Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04

when I right click on desktop I don't see create folder option in ubuntu.
please find the attached screenshot.

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

[image]

Comment: is the `desktop-icons` extension 0ff??